# IntelliJ IDEA filter hierarchy subtype

Tags: java, intellij-idea, hierarchy

Is there a way to filter hierarchy subtype in IntelliJ Idea?

For example, I would like to generate the class hierarchy for `java.util.Map.Entry<K, V>` but would like to display just the public classes and classes residing in `java.*` package.

Eclipse seems not to support this either and I can't see a way to directly do this from IDE UI so is there a way to achieve this or perhaps script it within IDEA itself?

EDIT: To clarify things, I wanted to find if there is already a simple and public implementation of `Entry<K, V>` within the JDK so that I don't need to write my own crufty code.

Turns out there are two good candidates (`SimpleEntry<K, V>` and `SimpleImmutableEntry<K, V>`, for those who may be interested) but I only managed to find them after some painstaking sifting through the myriad implementations of `Entry<K, V>` on my classpath (see [here](http://oi60.tinypic.com/10dbjub.jpg)).

What I want is to filter such deep type hierarchies according to package name and access modifier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what are you exactly trying to achieve, because you're talking about "*generating the class hierarchy*" and then you're talking about "*displaying just public items*".

I assume, that you would like to navigate to Hirarchy Tool Window (by pressing **CTRL-H** on selected type) and filter results, so that only types from desired package (`java.*`) will be displayed.

To achieve this, in Hirarchy Tool Window on the toolbar there is a "`Scope`" ComboBox. Click it and choose "`Configure...`". "`Scopes`" window will appear, where you can add and configure a new custom scope, which will filter the desired types for you.

[image]

EDIT:
I couldn't found in [scope languge syntax reference](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/scope-language-syntax-reference.html) any option for filtering based on access modifiers.

But I've googled a little bit and I think you might be looking for `Structural Search` (**CTRL+SHIFT+S**). You can also use here "Scopes" like described above, and also use access modifiers like this:

> public class $DerivedClass$ implements Entry {}

or

> private class $DerivedClass$ implements Entry {}

I haven't used it too much, but it's probably a very powerful tool and will help you achieve better results than Hirarchy Tool Window.

Reference: [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/ssr.html), [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/structural-search-and-replace.html) and [here](http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Basics_of_working_with_structural_search).

Comment: Thank you, I've clarified the initial question. Your answer is very close to what I needed and this is enough to accept it. For an added bonus - is there a way to further filter the scoped hierarchy via access modifiers? I could not find an option to do that.

Comment: I've updated my answer, maybe Structural Search is this what you're looking for.

Comment: Searching class hierarchy in JRE library(`rt.jar`) only:
Scope pattern: ``lib:java..*||lib:javax..*||lib:com.sun..*``
That's exactly what I looking for. thanks!